# How to convert .net Datetime object to google.protobuf.Timestamp

Tags: asp.net-core, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm using a gRPC connection on the project I'm working on and am having a problem with converting selected `Datetime` object to `google.protobuf.Timestamp`
every time I map Datetime to `google.protobuf.Timestamp` the mapped result in the minimum value of the `google.protobuf.Timestamp` which is `(1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.)`

Here's the mapping I'm using

```
CreateMap<DateTime, Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp>().ConvertUsing(x => Timestamp.FromDateTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind(x, DateTimeKind.Utc)));
```

```
CreateMap<Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(x => x.ToDateTime());
```

Comment: question: are you using the Google protobuf/grpc implementation, or protobuf-net? both of them will define this type, but in slightly different ways

Comment: import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
I'm using this on my proto file

Comment: that would be true for either; let me rephrase - do you have a minimal repro here that somebody here could run, that shows the result you're seeing?

Answer (score 3):

using `Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes`,

```
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.FromDateTime(datetime)
```